# Instantiating classes dynamically?

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation

Let's say I have this array:

```
String[] names = {"stack1", "stack2", "stack3"};
```

Is it possible to instantiate `Stack` dynamically using those names, so there will be 3 objects named `stack1`, `stack2`, and `stack`"? Later in the code, I'd like to call `stack1.pop()`, or `stack3.empty()`, for example.

I've been told to take a look at reflection, and still not sure how.

Comment: 24 questions asked, 0 answers accepted... I think I'll pass, thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java

Comment: @SJuan76 yeah, looking at his profile, he really does not bother :)

Comment: As others pointed out, you are supposed to accept the replies that do answer your questions.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* create objects via reflection if you have the class name in a `String`, for example.

You *can not* "dynamically" create "variables". For example:

```
String s = "foo";

// some magic that creates a variable identified by s

foo.callSomeMethod();
```

That **won't** work.

Variables in Java (fields, local variables and parameters) can *only* be created at compile time.

What you *can* do (and which is *sometimes* the correct approach) is to create a `Map<String,YourType>` and hold each newly created object via this map with a given `String`:

```
Map<String,MyType> map = new HashMap<String,MyType>;
String s = "foo";
map.put(s, new MyType());

// ...

map.get("foo").callSomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless `stack1` is a class in the default package you won't be able to create classes of that "type".

If it is just a variable name, you're missing the type anyways.

Have a look at the Java Compiler API that should allow you to dynamically create sources and then compile and use them. I haven't used it myself yet, but maybe this article could help: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html

Additionally, if you could elaborate a bit on what exactly you are trying, this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a map?

```
Map<String, Stack<String>> m = new HashMap<String, Stack<String>>();
m.put("stack1", new Stack<String>());
m.get("stack1").push("Hello!");
```

Comment: Well I'm just curious whether this is possible in Java or not. Anyway thanks for your hint, looks easier to me.