# Do some operations after insert into List

Tags: c#

i have following class:

```
public class FirstClass 
{
   public FirstClass()
   {
       list = new List<SomeType>();
   }

   public List<SomeType> list;
}
```

Is this possible to do some actions like fire different method after someone will put element into that list?

Comment: You deleted your question about creating a variable in C#. But just FYI, I asked a similar question before for curiosity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java It's in Java but most of the answers apply to C# as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [`ObservableCollection<SomeType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for this instead.

`ObservableCollection<T>` provides the `CollectionChanged` event which you can subscribe to - the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event fires when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should be using `ObservableCollection<T>`. It fires events when items are added or removed, or several other events.

Here is the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`List` does not expose any events for that. You should consider using [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) instead. It has `CollectionChanged` event which occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
        private List<SomeType> _list;

        public void AddToList(SomeType item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
        SomeOtherMethod();
    }

      public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeType> MyList
    {
       get { return _list.AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

but ObservableCollection would be best.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own implementation of IList you can call methods when an item is added to the list (or do anything else you want). Create a class that inherits from IList and have as a private member a list of type T. Implement each of the Interface methods using your private member and modify the Add(T item) call to whatever you need it to do

Code:

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> _myList = new List<T>();

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _myList.GetEnumerator(); }
        public void Clear() { _myList.Clear(); }
        public bool Contains(T item) { return _myList.Contains(item); }

        public void Add(T item) 
        { 
            _myList.Add(item);
            // Call your methods here
        }

         // ...implement the rest of the IList<T> interface using _myList
   }
```