# Declaring objects name using some loop

Tags: java, c++

How to create several objects of given class whose instances are pre known without manually declaring each object name.Means can i use some loop to declare those objects name from some other data type like (int,string etc.) which i can easily handle.

Comment: Create the objects in a loop, and put them to an array or map.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects don't have names - variables have names. When you declare a variable and initialize it (Java):

```
Person alice = new Person("Alice", 25);
```

then `alice` is the name of a variable, not the name of an object.

If you need to create objects in a loop and keep track of them, then use an array or a collection class such as `ArrayList` to keep track of the objects.

- [Java Tutorial: Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Java Tutorial: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve it. This is a Java solution putting the objects to a map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class C {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, C> map = new HashMap<String, C>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
      map.put("Object " + i, new C());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `map["Object " + i] = new C();` That is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks, replaced it with .put