# Int from value of a String in android

Tags: android

I have

```
String[] x1 = new String[] { "05:30", "07:20", "13:30", "21:30"};
String[] x2 = new String[] { "08:30", "01:20"}; 
String[] x3 = new String[] { "12:30", "00:20", "13:54"};
```

From a database I receive x1 or x2 or x3 name.

```
String get_x = null;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        get_x = cursor.getString(0); // get_x will have value x1 or x2 or x3
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

And then I want to get size of returned x[1 or 2 or 3]
eg. int size = x1.length, where x1 is value of get_x string.

I tried

```
int size = get_x.length;
```

but not working. 'size' will be equal with length of get_x, not length of x1.length

Comment: What is get_x? you define it as String, so String.valueOf seems redundant.

Comment: String get_x = new String(); is redundant; "new String()" will be recycled as get_x is assigned just a few lines below.

Comment: I edited but still not working.

Comment: what do you mean by size? you want to know how many values you have in your array? like in x1 you have 4?

Comment: @Roman Rozenshtein, yes, exactly.

Comment: I have posted an answer that will give you the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using reflection :).
Pass get_x to the method.
"YourClassName" - is the name of your Activity (or the class hosting your code), replace it.

```
            public void getSize(String arrayParamName){
                Field[] fields = YourClassName.class.getDeclaredFields();

                for (Field field : fields) {

                    //gives the names of the fields
                    if(field.getName().equals(arrayParamName)) {
                        System.out.println(field.getName());
                        try {

                            String[] returnedArrayFromDB = (String[])field.get(CameraActivity.this);
                            System.out.println("length of " +field.getName() + ":  "+ returnedArrayFromDB.length);
                            System.out.println("first value of array " +returnedArrayFromDB[0]);


                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: many thanks.
One more question, is it possible to read a value from x1 using for?
e.g.

for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
 field.getName()[i];
}

Comment: See edited version. After you cast the field to String[] you can use it as usual.

Comment: With that said and I am glad that it did resolved your problem, I encourage you to use a different approach in the future as Code-Apprentice wrote. In short, it can be done but reflection is not what you would like to use in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use a more appropriate data structure for your program. You have several options:

1. Store the value directly in the database rather than storing a value which acts as an "index" for the value.
2. Change your database to return an `int` value (e.g. 1, 2, or 3) rather than a `String` (e.g. `"x1"`, `"x2"`, `"x3"`) and use an an array or `List` instead of three separate variables. The `int` value from the database will act as an index to your array or `List`.
3. Leave your database as it is and use `Map` rather than three distinct variables. Now you can use the value from the database as an index into your `Map`.

The following questions on Stack Overflow are related to your issue:

[Is it possible to create variables at runtime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java?lq=1)

[How to create a variable with a user-defined name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617377/how-to-create-a-variable-with-a-user-defined-name-in-java)