# Name and lifetime of variables at compile time

Tags: java, c++, scope, lifetime

From all the languages that I know (Java, C++), the name and the lifetime of a variable is always known at compile time. Is there any language for which the name and lifetime will be bound at run time?

Furthermore, I'm playing with C++ smart pointers at the moment. When is the life time known as well as the scope?

Comment: JavaScript, python perhaps? (Not sure)

Comment: Variables don't have lifetimes; *objects* do.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good point.

Comment: In Java you know the lifetime of an object at compile time?

Comment: Scope is known at compile time. Lifetime in general is not.

Comment: The question is very vague.... What is "variable"? Objects can have dynamic properties, even in C++ if you inherit from base object which supports them, and then these may be indistinguishable from properties defined at compile time, when accessing the instnce from a more dynamic language like Javascript or Python. Example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty

Comment: I fail to understand, what is the use of a variable that you don't know the name of? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

With C++ smart pointers, the scope of the smart pointer is the regular scope. The scope of the managed object is determined by the smart pointers behavior.

There are a lot of languages that employ dynamic/runtime scoping. Javascript, PERL, PHP is a few. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Dynamic_scoping

Answer (score 0):

with java, NO *a priori* , or very difficult

see this: [Is it possible to create variables at runtime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java)

What can you do with that at runtime ?

You can reference variables,  as you want (in an array, integer, in a Map ...)