# selenium java, generic method with constant

Tags: java, selenium, constants

I'm using selenium with java and I'm trying to find a better way to work with radio button

In this example, I have a set of 3 radio button with the same name

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" />Foo
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />Bar
<input type="radio" name="test" value="3" />Foobar
```

I would like to make a class that extends (or use) selenium webelement to be able to use this more easily without having to rely on the value once it's declared.
So something like (the syntax probably don't exists, but it may give you an idea of what I would like to achieve)

```
MyRadio myRadioInstance = new MyRadio(By.ByName("test")) {
    declareValues() {
        FOO(1);
        BAR(2);
        FOOBAR(3);
    }
};
```

And after using it something like that

```
myRadioInstance.isSelected(myRadioInstance.FOO);
myRadioInstance.select(myRadioInstance.FOO);
```

Doing so, I don't have to hardcode everywhere in my code that the value of Foo is 2 and it will be only for this particular radio set.

If possible I would like to rely on somesort of constant or enum insted of string for "Foo/Bar/Foobar" to prevent the maximum of error once it's declared.

Is it something that can be done in java or I am just dreaming of the impossible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in java we cannot directly generate varibales in runtime, it is almost impossible to create a class with constants or enums for different number radio elements.

[Is it possible to create variables at runtime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java)

The best we can do is using maps to create a generic class which can handle radios.

```
public class MyRadio {
    // map to store radios
    Map<String, WebElement> elementMap = new HashMap<String, WebElement>(); 

    MyRadio(By by) {
        // find all radios
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
        // iterate through radios and add to a map
        for (WebElement element: elements) {
            elementMap.put("radio"+element.getAttribute("value"), element);
        }     
    }

    public WebElement getRadio(String radioName) {
        if (elementMap.contains(radioName)) {
            return elementMap.get(radioName);
        }
        // might want to throw a custom exception here like noRadioFoundException
        return null;
    }
}


MyRadio myRadioInstance = new (By.ByName("test"));
myRadioInstance.getRadio("radio1");
myRadioInstance.getRadio("radio2");
```

The name of the radio in the map is `radio + radio value`. we can change it as per your will.

We can add validation methods like is `radioFound(radioName)`, `getAllRadioNames()` to make the class robust.