# Can I name a variable based on a value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array can I use the values inside of it to name variables?

So far I have tried...

```
String Statement = "Please enter the ";
String[] Variables = {"Weight", "Length", "Height", "Width", 
"Zones"};


for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        double Array.get(Variables, x) = UI.askDouble(Statement + Variables[x] + " (kg): ");
    }
```

With no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create variables at runtime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478833/is-it-possible-to-create-variables-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: I think it is possible to name your variable the same as a value in your array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want you want is possible, but a map is one data structure which might better fit what you have in mind:

```
Map<String, Double> vals = new HashMap<>();
vals.put("Weight", 100.5d);
vals.put("Length", 2.0d);
// now access those keys
System.out.println("Weight = " + vals.get("Weight");
```

Or, better yet, you could define a POJO with these fields, e.g.

```
public class Measurements {
    private double weight;
    private double length;
    private double height;
    private double width;
    private double zones;

    // constructor and getters/setters
}
```

Then, you may use this POJO as a wrapper to store all the values of interest at once.