# How to loop assigning characters in a string to variable?

Tags: loops, groovy

I need to take a string and assign each character to a new string variable for a Text To Speech engine to read out each character separately, mainly to control the speed at which it's read out by adding pauses in between each character.

The string contains a number which can vary in length from 6 digits to 16 digits, and I've put the below code together for 6 digits but would like something neater to handle any different character count.

I've done a fair bit of research but can't seem to find a solution, plus I'm new to Groovy / programming.

```
OrigNum= "12 34 56"
Num = OrigNum.replace(' ','')
sNum = Num.split("(?!^)")
sDigit1 = sNum[0]
sDigit2 = sNum[1]
sDigit3 = sNum[2]
sDigit4 = sNum[3]
sDigit5 = sNum[4]
sDigit6 = sNum[5]
```

Edit: The reason for needing a new variable for each character is the app that I'm using doesn't let the TTS engine run any code. I have to specifically declare a variable beforehand for it to be read out

Sample TTS input: "The number is [var:sDigit1] [pause] [var:sDigit2] [pause]..."

I've tried using [var:sNum[0]] [var:sNum[1]] to read from the map instead but it is not recognised.

Comment: why do you need a new (?) variable per char?

Comment: Original post updated, this is required for TTS to work as it doesn't run code

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479202/3355860) about dynamically creating variable names.

You could use a map in your stuation, which is cleaner and more groovy:

```
Map digits = [:]
OrigNum.replaceAll("\\s","").eachWithIndex { digit, index ->
    digits[index] = digit
}

println digits[0]       //first element == 1
println digits[-1]      //last element == 6
println digits.size()   // 6
```

Comment: Thanks but a Map won't work as each digit needs its own variable, I've updated my original post for clarity around this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you need, but to convert your input String to output you could use:

```
String origNum = "12 34 56"
String out = 'The number is ' + origNum.replaceAll( /\s/, '' ).collect{ "[var:$it]" }.join( ' [pause] ' )
```

gives:

> The number is [var:1] [pause] [var:2] [pause] [var:3] [pause] [var:4] [pause] [var:5] [pause] [var:6]

Comment: Thanks, at first I wasn't sure the [pause] being part of the string would be understood by TTS but it did!